# Eclipse Remote System Explorer problems

Tags: eclipse

I just installed this plugin in Eclipse Indigo, hoping to have a nice and clean way to access FTP and SSH sites while working in Eclipse.

However, I cannot connect to neither SSH nor FTP sites. I'm sitting on the same computer, connecting to FTP and SSH with FlashFXP and Putty without troublw. But when I put these servers into connections in the RSE in Eclipse, I get connection refused errors when trying to access the servers/sites.

SSH gives this error:

> ```
> java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
> ```

FTP gives this error:

> ```
> Operation failed with exception
> 'java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect'
> ```

There is no error in the console when selecting "Connect" for the connections - the errors pop up when I try browsing "My Home" or "Root" for the connection.

Any ideas? I am working through a Cisco AnyConnect VPN connection, but since I can FTP and SSH with other clients, I find it strange that Eclipse won't let me.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have the same.

Answer (score 4):

Change the proxy setting to **direct connection**,  because eclipse uses default proxy. so change it to direct.

Comment: Hm. I might be a little blind here, but where do I find the proxy settings? They're not in the properties of the connection I've created.

Comment: Right click on the Remote system Connection you have created-> **properties**-> 'select' **Host** -> 'Click on' **Configure proxy setting** -> Change the **Active provider** to Direct in **Network Connections**.

Comment: There is no "Configure proxy setting" in Properties -> Host. The only options are these: Host name, Connection name, Default user ID, Description, Verify host name and Default encoding.

Comment: There is no **Configure Proxy Setting** _(in blue color)_ in between **Verify Hostname** and **Default Encoding** ?

Comment: It should be there, else try installing the RSE plugin again.

Comment: I reinstalled the plugin (using the links method), and now I've got the proxy settings. However, I still cannot connect. It might be worth to mention than in the net I'm working, ssh is disabled. But I'm using a VPN connection in where ssh is enabled. So, I'm able to connect to the server with putty (ssh client) but not with the RSE plugin. Even though I changed the network connections setting to direct.

Comment: just reinstalled windows and was getting this, turned out to be windows firewall issues

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after days of searching i found the only solution is reverting to Java 6,

Java 7 was causing all these errors

like everything free you are left on your own with no support

Even though I solved the problem, I am back to using Dreamweaver, the support alone is worth the money